# Wrong superscript placement with `hepparticles`

Tags: spacing, superscripts

I am writing a thesis on theoretical particle physics and need some particle names. I stumbled upon [`hepnames`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hepnames) which in turn uses [`hepparticles`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hepparticles). After I changed my whole document, I realized that the placement of superscript is messed up by this package. That is even in normal math, not only when you use its commands.

Without `hepparticles`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\begin{document}
\( q^j \quad e^\ell \quad m_{q^j} \quad m_{e^\ell} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: without hepparticles]

With `hepparticles`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\begin{document}
\( q^j \quad e^\ell \quad m_{q^j} \quad m_{e^\ell} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: with hepparticles]

Apart from that I really like the package and would not like having to revert all my changes (I'd probably redefine the ones I used myself, but I don't know how to do it in a math and non-math safe way, as the package does). Is there any known fix? Should I contact the package creator and file a bug?

(I would like to tag this question as `hepparticles`, but it doesn't exist and I don't have the rep…)

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for example; it has never been meant for this.

Comment: The package loads `subdepth`, which is responsible for this appalling output.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the info, I changed it. Doesn't change the behavior, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is due to the package `subdepth` which tries to fix something and breaks several others. `;-)`

You return to normal by loading `subdepth` with the `low-sup` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\begin{document}
\( q^j \quad e^\ell \quad m_{q^j} \quad m_{e^\ell} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]